# Is an anticompaction expected with a sub-range repair?

Tags: cassandra

We have 5 node cassandra cluster(cassandra `4.1` version) with Replication factor 3, Read & Write consistency as `QUORUM`. We are using STCS (Size Tier Compaction Strategy).

I triggered sub range repair on cassandra 4.1, and anti compaction observed on the sstables.
When repair is running,  `nodetool compactionstats -H` provided below output.

```
pending tasks: 1
- operations.performance: 1

id                                   compaction type             keyspace   table       completed total     unit  progress
37050c60-d632-11ed-aef5-e3575e5adfab Anticompaction after repair operations performance 39.61 GiB 63.62 GiB bytes 62.26%  
Active compaction remaining time :   0h25m36s
```

```
$ nodetool version
ReleaseVersion: 4.1.0
```

command used:

```
$ nodetool repair -st -09183985968492985983 -et -09163001156344214513
```

Is this expected ? I was under impression that "sub range repair" will not trigger anti compaction.

Sub Range repair on cassandra 3.11.3 version, didn't trigger anti compaction.

Thanks

I was expecting no anti compaction during sub range repair.

Comment: Not sure of the level of write activity of this cluster, but that itself could trigger (anti) compaction.

Answer (score 1):

An anti-compaction operation is normal particularly for sub-range repairs because the repaired ranges in a SSTable need to be split from the unrepaired data.

Let me use the following conditions to illustrate:

1. repair triggered for token range `[101, 200]`
2. SSTable A contains partitions which map to tokens in the range `[50, 300]`

In this scenario, once the sub-range repair completes then:

3. a subset of the data (token range `[101, 200]`) contained in SSTable A is repaired, but
4. the data in token ranges `[50, 99]` and `[201, 300]` are *not* repaired.

To deal with this situation, the SSTable has to be anti-compacted to separate the repaired data (3) from the un-repaired data (4) into their own SSTables. Cheers!

Comment: Ok I understand. Why this is not happening in cassandra 3.11.3 version when sub range repair is used. Is this something changed ? Is there a way to run sub range repair without triggering anti compaction. Since anti compaction is the one which is taking most of the time during repair.

Comment: That's a misconception. The behaviour is the same because the same conditions apply even in C* 3.11 where repaired vs un-repaired need to be split. Cheers!

Comment: Amount of time taking repair for the same set of data in cassandra 3.11 version vs cassandra 4.1 version is very huge. When I run node tool compactionstats on cassandra 3.11 version during sub range repair, I only see validation step.